# jsforce metadata.deploy, deployment id

Tags: salesforce, jsforce

I am looking to get the created deployment id returned in the callback, how do I get it immediately when it is created ?
This is from the jsforce documentation. Here it is called only when it is completed.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var zipStream = fs.createReadStream("./path/to/MyPackage.zip");
conn.metadata.deploy(zipStream, { runTests: [ 'MyApexTriggerTest' ] })
  .complete(function(err, result) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    console.log('done ? :' + result.done);
    console.log('success ? : ' + result.true);
    console.log('state : ' + result.state);
    console.log('component errors: ' + result.numberComponentErrors);
    console.log('components deployed: ' + result.numberComponentsDeployed);
    console.log('tests completed: ' + result.numberTestsCompleted);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was dead simple, I was able to figure out this, just use the callback without the complete.